# Error in height for plotting grouped bar chart in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart by scenerio with the following data set from my excel sheet:

```
Scenerio Migration  Foraged Counter
1            0        741    1500
2            1        740    1500
3           200       475    1349
4           198       215    832
5           184       118    616
6           151        52    412
7           139        31    343
8           134        21    304
9           131        14    278
```

My x axis should be scenerio type and the y axis should be the average score. The grouped columns should be migration and foraged. I've tried running this several different ways and I keep getting this error  `'height' must be a vector or a matrix`. How do I make a grouped bar chart with this data set?

Here are just a few attempts:

```
   1.  barplot(dat, col = c("darkblue", "red"), beside = TRUE, legend = rownames (dat))

   2.  barplot(dat, beside = T, ylim = c(0,1600), col = dat$Scenerio, axis.lty = "solid")

3. condition <- c(dat$Migration, dat$Foraged)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat$Scenerio, y=dat$Counter, fill=condition)) +geom_bar(position = position_dodge())
```

Comment: *"tried running this several different ways"* ... it helps to know what you've tried, for two reasons: (1) our answer or comments can be geared specifically to the code you're attempting; and (2) it demonstrates effort on questions here. While #1 is certainly the more important of the two, the lack of attempted code in a question can make it appear that there has been no effort. Thanks! (But more important for #1 ... and since we don't see your code, we can't point out a mistake.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ggplot` solution will imply to pivot your dataframe into a longer format such as:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% pivot_longer(-Scenerio) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(Scenerio), y = value, fill = name))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

A base r solution using `barplot` will imply to transpose your dataframe and convert as a matrix as follow:

```r
rownames(df) <- df$Scenerio
df <- t(df[,-1])
colnames(df) <- 1:9

barplot(df, beside = TRUE, legend = rownames(df), 
        xlab = "Scenario", ylab = "Score")
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible example**

```r
structure(list(Scenerio = 1:9, Migration = c(0L, 1L, 200L, 198L, 
184L, 151L, 139L, 134L, 131L), Foraged = c(741L, 740L, 475L, 
215L, 118L, 52L, 31L, 21L, 14L), Counter = c(1500L, 1500L, 1349L, 
832L, 616L, 412L, 343L, 304L, 278L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```